# How often JTable call getValueAt()?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, abstracttablemodel

How often my **JTable** call **getValueAt()** from AbstractTableModel?

Is it will be normal, if I will make big calculations in **getValueAt()** (for example, calculate value of polynomial)? Should I store values of polynomial in array and return from it?

Comment: The getValueAt() method should be very efficient because the method can be called frequently. Every time you scroll, every time you change row selection etc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is called often; in fact you can see how often by putting in a print statement and watch it fill up your console window. I recommend caching your polynomials if they're expensive to compute, though this is true for all computations everywhere, not just for polynomials in a `JTable`.

Comment: Thank you. I put counter at the getValueAt() and all become clear. getValueAt() calls by table every time, when I resize window, when I click on cell. @camickr said it in comment.